# Java, reading in a lifes of strings and numbers and putting them in an array

Tags: java, arrays

So I have been trying to read from a file which has lines of both strings and numbers, and input this into an array. Is there a way to correctly implement this? So far I have tried:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i = +3){
    if(readFile2.readLine() instanceof String){

    }
    if(readFile2.readLine() instanceof String){
        arrays[0][count] = readFile2.readLine();
        count++;
    }

}
```

where the array is an int, however this gives me a type mismatch error as the array is an int and the file has both ints and strings. Thank you!

*Note: I have i = i+3 because every three things on the list, is the integer that I want inputted to the array, the strings are not inputted at all.)

Comment: Every call to `readLine` advances to the next line. Right now you are only reading every 3rd line. Perhaps you want to use [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-). Also, your `for` loop should have `i += 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code block it may help you

```
String value;
while ((value = readFile2.readLine()) != null) {
  if (value.matches("[0-9]*$")) {
    //TODO Integer part
  } else {
    //TODO Text part
  }
}
```

Comment: I have number values ranging to the hundreds, how to I put that into the (value.matches()) statement? *I'm kinda noob

Comment: value.matches("[0-9]*$") handle numeric pattern, it returns true for all numeric values. copy and paste this code without any change